# Save text file in Apache Spark with specific format of the content

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I have a dataframe in Apache Spark that looks like this:

```
+----------+--------------------+
|sourcemmsi|         coordinates|
+----------+--------------------+
| 205204000|(-5.6873484,48.34...|
| 205204000|(-5.5797615,48.32...|
| 205204000|(-5.35488,48.2976...|
| 205204000|(-5.1845317,48.04...|
| 205204000|(-5.202,48.013206...|
| 205204000|(-5.2196136,47.98...|
| 205204000|(-5.3232217,47.84...|
| 205204000|(-5.5193834,47.67...|
| 205204000|(-5.46604,47.7264...|
| 205204000|(-5.326638,47.828...|
| 205204000|(-5.3041234,47.87...|
| 205204000|(-5.282315,47.910...|
| 205204000|(-5.224315,48.000...|
| 205204000|(-5.072748,48.160...|
| 205204000|(-4.459872,48.898...|
| 205439000|(-6.4076085,48.07...|
| 205439000|(-6.395923,48.178...|
| 205439000|(-6.34157,48.3732...|
| 205439000|(-5.5648932,48.24...|
| 205439000|(-5.5401783,48.16...|
+----------+--------------------+
```

The first column is type of integer while the second one is string (based on the command `printSchema()` ). What I want to achieve, is to create a text file where each of its line would look like that:

```
{205204000, (-5.6873484,48.34, 43.43), (-5.5797615,48.32,12.54) ... }
{205439000, (-5.5401783,48.16, 41.21), (-6.34157,48.3732,43.25) ... }
```

What I basically want is to group-by my data based on the **sourcemmsi** and after that create a text file that would have the format as mentioned above. Is that possible?

e.g I am using pySpark

Comment: Why plaintext output instead of json? That way, you can actually parse the values later?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming we have this dataset called `ds`:

```
+----------+-------------+
|sourcemmsi|coordinates  |
+----------+-------------+
|205204000 |(-5.6, 47.34)|
|205204000 |(-5.5, 46.34)|
|205204000 |(-5.4, 45.34)|
|205439000 |(-5.3, 31.34)|
|205439000 |(-3.1, 34.34)|
|205439000 |(-5.2, 33.34)|
|205439000 |(-1.1, 32.34)|
|205439000 |(-2.4, 31.34)|
+----------+-------------+
```

You can use the following statements:

```scala
ds
  // we first group by 
  .groupBy("sourcemmsi")
  // then we collect grouped values to list, and we concatenate them with `,`
  .agg(array_join(collect_list("coordinates"), ",").as("coordinates"))
  // we use a `selectExpr` to create the rows in the format that we want, eg. {sourcemssi,coordinates}
  .selectExpr("concat('{', sourcemmsi, ',', coordinates, '}') as data")
  // finally, we write it to a destination path
  .write.text("C:/Users/LabinotVila/Desktop/text")
```

To get to this result:

```
{205204000,(-5.5, 46.34),(-5.6, 47.34),(-5.4, 45.34)}
{205439000,(-2.4, 31.34),(-3.1, 34.34),(-5.2, 33.34),(-5.3, 31.34),(-1.1, 32.34)}
```

which is simply a text file. I hope this helps, good luck!